# Mongoose $substr part of selected query

Tags: mongodb, select, mongoose, populate

I'm using Mongoose to retrieve some data. I have a function where I populate a collection. I use select to get specific parts from the database.

I selected the field "text", but I only want a substring of the text to be retrieved. How can I get this done.

This is the function:

```
.exec(function(err, sub_docs){
        subcollection.find({_id: id})
        .populate({path: 'messages', select: 'title date url type text'})

          .lean().exec(function(err, messages) {
          res.render(main_item, {sub:sub_docs, messages: messages});
        });
      });
```